# Hide or Collapse a single specific row in ag-grid using Javascript

Tags: javascript, hide, ag-grid

After a lot of search in SO without any particular solution, I am compelled to ask this question.
In Simple words - I want to collapse or hide a specific row using Javascript in ag-grid. I have tried several methods explained in ag-grid documentation and also in SO, but none has worked till now.

All the following methods have been tried and none of the codes worked.

```
Let rowNode = gridOptions.api.getRowNode(params.value);

Method #1. params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(2).setExpanded(false);
Method #2. params.api.getRowNode(params.value).setExpanded(false);
Method #3. gridOptions.api.setRowNodeExpanded(rowNode,false);
Method #4. gridOptions.api.getRowNode(rowId).style.visibility = "collapse";
```

I have also tried using plain CSS, like this - Data has disappeared but the white blank row is visible

```
rowNode.setDataValue('class', 'hidden'); //Where “class” is a field

const gridOptions = {
    //Other grid options...
  getRowClass: params => {
        if (params.data.class === "hidden") {
            return 'hidden';
        }
},
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nvtqhz?file=infoCellRenderer.js

Comment: can you share a stackblitz

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to hide the row which is clicked with the link “Click Me”. The reason, I don’t want to remove the row is because, later I should be able to unhide the row. Thanks much.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nvtqhz?file=infoCellRenderer.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setExpand / setRowNode Expanded only works on collapsible rows, i.e it will collapse an expanded row. it will not hide it.
I edited your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vrujex?file=index.js),
I made a couple of changes to make it work.

1. [Selectable Rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/)
   So, when you click a row, I'm marking it as selected. There is a property on ag-grid `rowSelection: 'single' | 'multiple`. If you want to hide only one row at a time, use 'single' if you can hide multiple rows use 'multiple'
2. [External filtering](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-external/)
   So, ag grid can filters rows if we provide a criteria.It can be a check on any of data property as well. For your problem, I have added a filter that says if any row is selected, remove it from the grid.
   Following are the changes

```
/// method called on clicking the button
function hideRow(params) {
  let rowNode = gridOptions.api.getRowNode(params.value); // get the clicked row
  rowNode.setSelected(true); //mark as selected
  gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged(); // trigger filter change
}
```

Triggering the filter change will call this method for each row

```
function doesExternalFilterPass(node) {
  return !node.selected; // if row node is selected dont show it on grid.
}
```

You can access the rows hidden any time using
`gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows() //Returns an array of data from the selected rows.`  OR
`gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes() //Returns an array of the selected nodes.`
And, if you want to show a row again, just filter from this above mentioned method and do these steps

```
rowNode.setSelected(false); //mark as unselected
gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged(); // trigger filter change
```

This will automatically show the row on grid.
Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You have saved me hours. This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: How can the external filter be applied after sorting?